# Python pyodbc - Compare Two Databases: How to Update, Insert, Delete one based on the Other

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

Here's the setup: 
I have two databases, one is read only and other will be written to. Currently each time the "read" database is polled the "write" database's rows are deleted and reinserted. Unfortunaly, during this polling process the information is displayed inaccurate until the poll completes. I am having a difficult time writing proper conditionals that will tell the "write" database to update if "read" information exists in "write" database, delete if not, and insert if new.

Below is my attempt to achieve my goal.

**sql_cam** pulls information from "read" database. 
**cam_check** pulls info from "write" database.

```
for s,d in zip(sql_cam, cam_check):
            try:
                    if s[0] != d[1]:
                            print 'delete, insert'
                            cursor.execute("""DELETE FROM CamTable WHERE client=?
                                            INSERT INTO CamTable(client, guid, camera, ip, model, firmware, CreationDate)
                                            VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                                           """, client_name, client_name, s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5])
                            cnxn.commit()
                    else:
                            print 'update'
                            cursor.execute("""
                            UPDATE CamTable SET camera=?, ip=?, model=?, firmware=?, CreationDate=?
                            WHERE guid=?
                            """, d[1])
                            cnxn.commit()

            except pyodbc.error:
                    pass
```

Comment: Define _“'read' information exists in 'write' database”_. Without a proper definition you cannot write conditions as you don't know what to test. What does that mean? That a row exists where all fields are equal? That a row exists that has the same id? Something else? Write it down in English and the code will write itself afterwards.

Comment: If information is in the "read only" database insert, delete, or update the "write" database. Basically, I just want to compare and copy one database to another.

Comment: So, that means you cannot ever have two rows with the exact same values? Do you have a unique index defined, then?

Comment: Yes, the guid and mac will always be unique.

Comment: Then just don't delete anything. Go ahead and always try to `INSERT` the row first. If it fails because of the unique constraint, then `UPDATE` it instead. Let the database worry about row unicity, that's its job.